# Is there any group-like structure that doesn't have an identity, but has (non-equal) left and right identities?

Tags: abstract-algebra

Is there any group-like structure that doesn't have an identity, but has a  (non-equal) left and right identities?

Comment: If both left identity and right identity exist, they are definitely the same.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Suppose you have some sort of collection of symbols and a binary operation on the collection represented by concatenation. If $L$ is a left identity and $R$ is a right identity, then
$$
L = LR = R
$$
and so they are actually the same.

Answer (score 1):

If both left identity and right identity exist, they are definitely the same, as @davidlowryduda pointed out.

But we can construct a structure that doesn't have an identity, but have either left identity or right identity.

Let set $G = \{ a, b \}$, where $a \neq b$.
Define$$
\def\opair#1{\langle #1 \rangle}
 \times = \{
  \opair{\opair{a,b},b},
  \opair{\opair{b,a},a},
  \opair{\opair{a,a},a},
  \opair{\opair{b,b},b}
 \}.
$$

Obviously, $\times$ is a binary arithmetic operation,
while both $a$ and $b$ are left identities of $G$.
Because
\begin{align*}
 (a \times a) \times a = a = a \times (a \times a), \\
 (a \times a) \times b = b = a \times (a \times b), \\
 (a \times b) \times a = a = a \times (b \times a), \\
 (b \times a) \times a = a = b \times (a \times a), \\
 (a \times b) \times b = b = a \times (b \times b), \\
 (b \times a) \times b = b = b \times (a \times b), \\
 (b \times b) \times a = a = b \times (b \times a), \\
 (b \times b) \times b = b = b \times (b \times b),
\end{align*}
then $\times$ is associative.

Therefore, $(G,\times)$ is a semigroup with two left identities but no right identity.